# how to use xpath on file xml

Tags: xml, xpath, dtd

I built some xml file and also declared a DTD.

This is the xml file with dtd declared:

Now, I would like to work the xpath syntax.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "yes" ?>

<!DOCTYPE farms[
    <!ELEMENT farms (farm+,worker+)> 
    <!ELEMENT farm (name, manager*, product+)> 
    <!ELEMENT product (name, type, cost)> 
    <!ELEMENT worker (name, phone)> 
    <!ELEMENT manager (name, phone)> 
    <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT type (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT phone (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT cost (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST farm
        fid ID #REQUIRED
        address CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST product
        pid ID #REQUIRED> 
    <!ATTLIST worker
        mid IDREF #IMPLIED
        fid IDREF #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST manager
        mid ID #REQUIRED>
    ]>



<farms> 
            <farm fid = "1" address="beer-sheva">
                <name>Neve Noy</name>
                <manager mid="2">
                    <name> RONI </name>
                    <phone>0545555572</phone>
                </manager>
                <manager mid = "3">
                    <name> DANI </name>
                    <phone>0545555542</phone>
                </manager>
                <product pid="4">
                    <name>Olive Oil</name>
                    <type>oil</type>
                    <coast>700</coast>
                </product>
            </farm>
            
            
            <farm fid="5" address="beer-sheva">
                <manager mid="6">
                    <name> Yossi </name>
                    <phone>0545555422</phone>
                </manager>
                <manager mid="9">
                    <name> Ron </name>
                    <phone>0545553222</phone>
                </manager>
                <product pid="8">
                    <name>Olive Oil</name>
                    <type>oil</type>
                    <coast>700</coast>
                </product>
            </farm>
    
    
            <worker mid = "2" fid = "1">
                <name> RONI </name>
                <phone> 0545555572</phone>
            </worker>       
            <worker mid = "3" fid = "1">
                <name> Dani </name>
                <phone>0545555572</phone>
            </worker>
            <worker fid="1">
                <name> Matan </name>
                <phone>05432323422</phone>
            </worker>
    
            
            //Worker than work in fram 5
            
            <worker mid="6" fid ="5">
                <name> Yossi </name>
                <phone>0545555422</phone>
            </worker>
            <worker mid="9" fid ="5">
                <name> Ron </name>
                <phone>0545553222</phone>
            </worker>
            <worker fid="5">
                <name> Haim </name>
                <phone>05432323422</phone>
            </worker>
            
</farms>
```

so what I tried to do is use the ID and idref in xpath, but when I try do to for example:

```
//worker/id(fid)[@fid = "1"]/manager/name/text()
```

it does not recognize that @fid it is a key
and it my first time using the xml and dtd so maybe I didn't declare good.

Comment: its my first time in the world using  xml and dtd
What I'm trying to do is to learn how to play with syntax on xpath and see which elements come back to me
Now that I want to play with id and idref is like not recognizing that I have keys within the elements

Comment: so you are trying to find the name of the manager for a specific worker?

Comment: ummm i try do find all the workers that work at the farm that producer Olive oil and not management by manager Yossi ! @OldProgrammer

Comment: and also i try to understand how to work with id and idref in xpath... @OldProgrammer

Comment: can i path to farm from worker? @OldProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

XPATH doesn't really support the type of navigation you're talking about.  You have other options, though.

1. Reformat the XML so that the WORKER tags are children of the FARM where they work.
2. Make two passes through the XML, one to get the FARM id from the WORKER tag, and then a second pass to get the FARM information with the FARM id.

The first item is the better choice, because it makes your XML more clearly represent the data, but that's not always an option.